# How to get my chart back to normal on R?

Tags: r, charts, package, uninstallation

I had made a plot on R a while ago and now I need to make a change to add a title to it. I took my code and tryied to re-run it, but it doesn't look like what I had before. It was a Pareto Chart with legend and red-yellow gradient, now when I plot it, it doesn't have my legend and it's blue with grid. I think I installed ggplot2, but I didn't called it and I think it it's messing whit my plot. The demensions are off and lines like cex is not working and I don't know how to fix it, I already trying to uninstall the package, but I don't think it worked since I keep getting the same blue Pareto Chart.
I wanna know how to make the same plot that I was doing before.

Here is the link to the plots: [the blue pareto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFnTY.png), [the old one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AeL9.png)

This is the code:

```
library(qcc)
pareto2 <- c(0.6235685,0.5618261,0.3135217,0.4538191,0.3997403,0.5091719,0.5526803,0.5353629,0.3493655)
names(pareto2) <- seq(1,9,1)
pareto.chart(pareto2,ylab="Taxa de Inflação Média (%)",ylab2="Porcentagem Acumulada",xlab="Grupos",las=1,main="")
grupos <- c("Alimentação e bebidas","Habitação","Artigos de residência","Vestuário","Transportes","Saúde e cuidados pessoais","Despesas pessoais","Educação","Comunicação")
par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))
legend(y=4.3,x=0.1,legend=grupos,ncol=1,pch=c(49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57),cex=0.7)
```

Ps.: I had to update the R base and RStudio. Currently I have the newst.

Comment: What is the function `pareto.chart` from? Be sure to explicitly list any non-base packages that you've used.

Comment: I added now, it is from the qcc package.

Comment: please include the snapshots of the plots in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach:

The data:

```
library(qcc)
pareto2 <- c(0.6235685,0.5618261,0.3135217,0.4538191,0.3997403,0.5091719,0.5526803,0.5353629,0.3493655)
names(pareto2) <- seq(1,9,1)
grupos <- c("Alimentação e bebidas","Habitação","Artigos de residência","Vestuário","Transportes","Saúde e cuidados pessoais","Despesas pessoais","Educação","Comunicação")
```

Function to define warm gradient of colors

```
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow"))
```

chart:

```
pareto.chart(pareto2, ylab = "Taxa de Inflação Média (%)",
             ylab2 = "Porcentagem Acumulada", xlab = "Grupos",
             las = 1,main = "", col = colfunc(9))    
legend(x = 0.1, y = 0.85, legend = grupos, ncol = 1,pch = 16,cex = 0.7,
       col = colfunc(9))
```

[image]

The legend coordinates should be in fractions of the plotting area where x = 0 and y = 1 is the top left corner. If you do not like the color codding in the legend, you can revert to:

```
legend(x = 0.1, y = 0.85,legend = grupos, ncol = 1,cex = 0.7, pch = c(49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57))
```

or even

```
legend(x = 0.1, y = 0.85, legend = grupos, ncol = 1,cex = 0.7, pch = c(49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57), col = colfunc(9))
```